# Integer comparison in Python

Tags: python, integer, comparator, squish

I came across something odd. I'm kind of new with Python so sorry if this is basics.

```
a = 12
b = int(24/3)
x = (a < b)
```

From the debugger:
I have:

```
a (int) = 12
b (int) = 8
x (bool) = True
```

So it seems that 8 > 12 in this situation, I'm clueless here, any explanation?

PS: x = a < b does the same (without brackets)

**EDIT**
I'm using squish (automatic tests), and it seems that's the issue as I asked some colleagues to test the same snipet in squish and it did the same.

Comment: I get `x = False` for your code. Your debugger seems to mess things up

Comment: I too am getting x = False.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iVM0gW2W

Comment: That's not only my debugger,
if x was a if condition, it would go through too... (that's the issue by the way)

Comment: maybe show some more of your code, the error seems to be somewhere else

Comment: I'm using Squish software (automatic tests) in python. It seems that it's squish the issue as it's not only on my machine that it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [well-known behaviour](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-py.html#squish.int), though not exactly intuitive, behaviour of Squish. Your `int` call doesn't use the Python `int` function but rather invokes the `int` constructor for constructing an integer which can be passed to methods in the application under test (`setWidth` or so). I.e. Squish overrides the meaning of `int`.

You can use

```
import __builtin__
a = 12
b = __builtin__.int(24/3)
x = (a < b)
```

to enforce getting the Python `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Something is fundamentally wrong, perhaps in your debugger or another part of your code. Python is reasonably bug-free with basic arithmetic.

```
>>> a = 12
>>> b = 24/3
>>> a < b
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works just fine. There are no bugs. As others have suggested, something is wrong with your debugger. I'd suggest editing the question to include details about the environment you are using so we can replicate the issue.